# Homework - Providing Output F and other things

Tags: java, output, user-input, instance-variables

My task is to "design a class called employee that includes three instance variables, first name (string), last name (string), and monthly salary (double). Provide a constructor that initializes the threee instance variables. Provide set and get methods for each instance variable. [...] to get full credit, your programs should have no compilation errors and give correct outputs; they should also be well commented and appropriately formated."

Now, for all intents and purposes, this site helped me finish the shell of that homework yesterday, where I created the class, got the main to stop being annoying, initialized a constructor with 3 variables, and had set and get methods for them.

However, I also feel like I need to have some kind of actual instance variables that should be set'ed, get'ed, adn printf'ed out or something. Right now, the Command Prompt just self terminates on the first button press, because there's nothing for the program to actually DO.

In that way, I'm messing with my program as it will be displayed below. I can't quite get it to work, and would appreciate some insight into at least what I am doing wrong with the code below:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Employee
{

    public String FirstName, LastName; // String instance variables

    public double Salary; //double floating-point instance variable

    // main method begins program execution
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        // create Scanner to enable user input in Dos
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in );
    }

    // should introduce and initialize the constructor Employee
    public Employee( String fName, String lName, double empSalary )
        {
            FirstName = fName;
            LastName = lName;
            Salary = empSalary;
        }

// set First Name

    public void setFirstName( String Steven ) // set the First Name
    {
        FirstName = Steven;
    }

    public void setLastName( String Dorsey ) // set the Last Name
        {
            LastName = Dorsey;
        }
    public void setSalary( double empSalary ) // set the Employee Salary
    {
        Salary = empSalary;
    }



    public String displayMessage()
    {
        // This statement calls Employee and should
        // get the First Name from Input
        System.out.printf( "Please enter the First Name\n");
            getFirstName( string fName );
            {
                return FirstName;
            }

        System.out.printf( "Please enter the Last Name\n");
            getLastName( string lName ) ); // get the Last Name
            {
                return LastName;
            }

        System.out.printf( "Salary: $%.2f\n");
            getSalary( double empSalary )
            {
                return Salary;
            }
    }
} // End class
```

Now, here are my errors. provided this time by Textpad:

```
* Employee.java:54: error: ')' expected
getFirstName( string fName );
                                ^
* Employee.java:54: error: illegal start of expression
getFirstName( string fName );
                                       ^
* Employee.java:60: error: ')' expected
getLastName( string lName ) ); // get the Last Name
                               ^
* Employee.java:60: error: illegal start of expression
getLastName( string lName ) ); // get the Last Name
                                      ^
* Employee.java:60: error: ';' expected
getLastName( string lName ) ); // get the Last Name
                                       ^
* Employee.java:66: error: '.class' expected
getSalary( double empSalary )
                              ^
* Employee.java:66: error: ';' expected
getSalary( double empSalary )
```

Comment: I hope that is not too rude, but have you ever visited a single course of your programming class?

Comment: The contents of `displayMessage()` look *very* strange. What is that function supposed to do?!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

```
public class Employee { 

    public String FirstName, LastName; // String instance variables

    public double Salary; //double floating-point instance variable

  //should introduce and initialize the constructor Employee
    public Employee( String fName, String lName, double empSalary ) {
         FirstName = fName;
         LastName = lName;
         Salary = empSalary;
     }
   public void setFirstName( String Steven ) // set the First Name 
   { 
       FirstName = Steven; 
   }

    public void setLastName( String Dorsey ) // set the Last Name
     {
         LastName = Dorsey;
     }
    public void setSalary( double empSalary ) // set the Employee Salary
    {
     Salary = empSalary;
    }

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return FirstName;
    }
    public String getLastName()
    {
        return LastName;
    }
    public double getSalary(){
        return Salary;
    }

    public void displayEmployee(){
        System.out.println("FirstName : "+FirstName);
        System.out.println("LastName : "+LastName);
        System.out.println("Salary : "+Salary);
    }
  //main method begins program execution
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
     // create Scanner to enable user input in Dos
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in );
     System.out.println("Enter employee details :");
       Employee emp=new Employee(input.next(), input.next(), input.nextDouble());
       emp.displayEmployee();
    }

}// End of class
```

Comment: Thank you. You are awesome. :D YOu've given me more stuff to learn about regarding syntax as well. :)

Comment: In our current chapter, the textbook doesn't mention syntax for salaries or actual names. It did a course book name with user input to set, get, and display the coursebook name, and it did Balances and Deposits where the deposit had a set of code for adding to it before getting the balance from initialbalance. So I had no idea how different my context of scripting should look.

Comment: Just so you know, I mis-clicked last semester. That's why I accidently downvoted. As soon as I get 15 reputation, I'll be voting that up.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have semicolons after your function names.

So, the following:

```
getLastName( string lName ) ); // get the Last Name
    {
        return LastName;
    }
```

should instead be

```
getLastName( string lName ) ) // get the Last Name
    {
        return LastName;
    }
```

Hope it helps, I didn't read through the rest of the code.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't notice that. :)

Comment: So you mean a method inside a method is ok if he removes the semicolon?

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows that you probably have some misconceptions about how Java and programming languages in general work:

e.g. in the snippet:

```
public void setFirstName( String Steven ) // set the First Name 
{ 
    FirstName = Steven; 
}
```

the naming of the String parameter **Steven** is very peculiar. Most programmers would name the parameter **firstName** or **pFirstname** because it holds a String variable. In some cases the content of that variable might be "Steven". Please note how I wrote the parameter names in **bold** while the variable content is put in quotes. The concepts variable and parameter are important to grasp before you'r code will function right. You might want  to check your code along these lines for all the other concepts that you were asked to do in your assignment. Learning is about understanding the difference between a misconception and the right concept. Please don't get frustrated that your question got negative points. People on stackoverflow are expecting the people who ask questions to do the basic analysis of the problem themselves and then ask for help when they get stuck at a point where all the analysis didn't help.

Comment: Returning to this thread, I see your comment and recognize that I failed to respond, and you were correct. 

I was suffering from teh misconception that, in that specific assignment, the teacher expected us to use our Names as a parameter for the Method, instead of treating it like a professionally-designed block of code using the actual parameter. I was childishly mistaken regarding what I thought my instructor expected from me.